# Mariadb SQL syntax error when incrementing a variable in a while loop

Tags: while-loop, mariadb

I have a MariaDB database with a list of sites stored and their chronology (e.g. 1st to 5th c. CE). I need to export a table of all the sites active in the 1st c., in the 2nd c., etc. I wanted to avoid exporting individual tables for single centuries and then combining them, because I am frequently adding new sites and I am using this exported .csv to perform some actions in R.

I thought to create a WHILE loop to generate a single table, but I get this error:

> [42000][1064] (conn=4) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET Counter = Counter + 1; [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET Counter = Counter + 1;  END WHILE; END' at line 17

The code I am using is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE while_centuries()
BEGIN
  DECLARE Counter INT DEFAULT -1;

  WHILE Counter <= 11 DO
       SELECT site_list.site_code, site_name, st.type_name, cl.culture_type, startcentury, endcentury, site_altitude,
       geo_name, x,y, regions.region_name, available_data, bot, zoo, poll
-- BOT ZOO POLL are links to the UUIDs of the rows of plant_remains, pollen_remains and faunal_remains table.
FROM site_list

INNER JOIN regions ON site_list.region_id = regions.region_id
INNER JOIN geo_type gt on site_list.geo_feature = gt.geo_id
INNER JOIN site_type st on site_list.site_type = st.type_id
INNER JOIN culture_list cl on site_list.culture = cl.id_culture
WHERE startcentury <=Counter AND endcentury>=Counter

 SET Counter = Counter + 1;

  END WHILE;
```

where 11 is the last century I need and -1 is the first century I need.

I am sorry I am not fluent in programming. Could somebody help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a semicolon after `endcentury>=Counter`
to end the SELECT statement.

It is NOT the `SET Counter = Counter + 1`
statement actually causing the error.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it gives me another error 
> [42000][1064] (conn=4) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE Counter INT DEFAULT -1; [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE Counter INT DEFAULT -1;  WHILE Counter <= 11 DO SELECT site_...' at line 1

Comment: Looking closer, I think you have multiple syntax issues.  Check these things:

1) are semicolons used inside BEGIN and END?
2) you are returning some data.... but in a loop.  What are you doing with that returning data on each iteration of the loop?  Each time you SELECT, you get a new "result set" of data from the DB.  If you SELECT again, you get a different result set (for a new century), but that first set of data is gone now....

Comment: You are right, I thought I could get a table inclusive of every century, but maybe a while loop would just recreate the table at each loop. Is a while loop still the way to go you think?